# Sample with more samples at the begining and end of sample space

Tags: python, numpy

You can get evenly spaced numbers over a specified interval using [Numpy's Linspace](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html):

```py
$ import numpy as np
$ np.linspace(0,10,5)
>>> array([ 0. ,  2.5,  5. ,  7.5, 10. ])
```

I, however, want to sample more numbers at the beginning and end of my interval. For instance, if my interval was `[0-10]` and I wanted 5 samples. A good sample would be:

```
>>> array([0, 1, 5, 9, 10])
```

I know someone might say that there are many ways to sample this space, for instance: `[0, 0.5, 5, 9.5, 10]` is another good sample. I do not mind how it is sampled, I am only **interested in sampling methods which return more samples towards the beginning and end of my sample space**.

One solution would be to sample indices from a Gaussian distribution, and if you get a number near the mean of the distribution you draw a number closer to the beginning or end of your sample space. However, this method seems more complicated than it needs to be, and you are not guaranteed to get good samples.

Does anyone know of a good way to generate samples towards the beginning and end of a sample space?

Comment: Maybe you could join 3 linspaces, the middle one with less than the first and last. I'm not sure how the math would work though. (and I'm just getting into np myself)

Comment: @wjandrea That's a really good idea! And it would guarantee that you are getting linear spaced samples in each of the sections. The math wouldn't be too bad either. For instance, if you broke it up into 3 linspaces, then the first and the last linspace could get 75% of the original samples, while the middle linspace would get 25% of the samples. I will see if anyone else has more concrete ideas, but so far this is the best idea. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Watchdog101 breaking up the intervall into 3 linspaces will become very difficult for small number of samples (5 in your case). For larger number of samples, you'll get a visible kink in the distribution, so a continuous function looks better here too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you more samples to the **end** of the intervall:

```
np.sqrt(np.linspace(0,100,5))
array([  0.        ,   5.        ,   7.07106781,   8.66025404,  10.        ])
```

You can choose a higher exponent to get more frequent intervalls towards the ends.

To get more samples towards **beginning *and* end** of the intervall, make the original linspace symmetrical to 0 and then just shift it.

**General function:**

```
def nonlinspace(xmin, xmax, n=50, power=2):
    '''Intervall from xmin to xmax with n points, the higher the power, the more dense towards the ends'''
    xm = (xmax - xmin) / 2
    x = np.linspace(-xm**power, xm**power, n)
    return np.sign(x)*abs(x)**(1/power) + xm + xmin
```

Examples:

```
>>> nonlinspace(0,10,5,2).round(2)
array([  0.  ,   1.46,   5.  ,   8.54,  10.  ])
>>> nonlinspace(0,10,5,3).round(2)
array([  0.  ,   1.03,   5.  ,   8.97,  10.  ])
>>> nonlinspace(0,10,5,4).round(2)
array([  0. ,   0.8,   5. ,   9.2,  10. ])
```

Comment: @Stef, I didn't downvote, and I agree that a transformation is the right idea, but the sqrt transform only compresses the points at one end.  The example shown in the question has closer points at both ends of the interval.

Comment: A quadratic function grows for large x, but has lower values at the beginning. Hence you'll have few samples for low xs and more for high ones, as the result suggests...?

Comment: You could use, for example, the sine function on [-pi/2, pi/2], and scale the result as needed to match the given end points.

Comment: That's a nice idea @WarrenWeckesser was thinking a quadratic function but defining a sine/cosine to fit this case is much simpler

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser based on your idea I quickly implemented something like this: `((np.sin(np.linspace(-math.pi/2,math.pi/2,10)) + 1) / 2) * range`. It needs a little cleaning up but I think this is a good idea.

Comment: @Watchdog101 I think my function is pretty much complete now. You can select min and max and you can easyly adjust how much more frequent the points will be towards beginning and end of intervall (this would be more difficult with sin and the spacing for a power function looks better than for sin)

Answer (score 3):

You can rescale the `tanh` to get sequences with adjustable clumpiness:

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoidspace(low,high,n,shape=1):
    raw = np.tanh(np.linspace(-shape,shape,n))
    return (raw-raw[0])/(raw[-1]-raw[0])*(high-low)+low

# default shape parameter
sigmoidspace(1,10,10)
# array([ 1.        ,  1.6509262 ,  2.518063  ,  3.60029094,  4.8461708 ,
#         6.1538292 ,  7.39970906,  8.481937  ,  9.3490738 , 10.        ])
# small shape parameter -> almost linear points
sigmoidspace(1,10,10,0.01)
# array([ 1.        ,  1.99995391,  2.99994239,  3.99995556,  4.99998354,
#         6.00001646,  7.00004444,  8.00005761,  9.00004609, 10.        ])
# large shape paramter -> strong clustering towards the ends
sigmoidspace(1,10,10,10)
# array([ 1.        ,  1.00000156,  1.00013449,  1.01143913,  1.87995338,
#         9.12004662,  9.98856087,  9.99986551,  9.99999844, 10.        ])
```

Comment: This is also a really good answer. I upvoted your answer. I marked @Stefs answer as correct because he had his answer first. I, however, think this is an equally good answer. And is correct too. Thank you so much!

Comment: I would (try to) upvote it twice if it had a short docstring and pep8-ness ;-)